# FatalExecutionEngineError while using WebClient#UploadValues

Tags: c#, webclient

Im trying to execute a post request in loop in a different thread, which will run my method every X seconds. (using `Sleep()` to timeout)

The method:

```
private static NameValueCollection NameValueCollection = new()
{
    {"id", "1"},
    {"level", "100"},
    {"exp", "512"},
    {"points", "3453457"}
};

public void send() {               
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    client.Headers.Add("Test", "GameClient1");

    var returnedBytes = client.UploadValues("https://example.com/play.php", "POST", NameValueCollection); // crash here

    var serverOutputString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(returnedBytes);

    /* more */
}
```

The exception:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'An unrecoverable runtime error 
occurred. Error address: 0x73aa9d05 in thread 0x3834. Error code: 0xc00005. This error could
be an existing problem in CLR or in the unsafe or unverifiable parts of the user code. 
Common causes of this problem include user errors in marshalling for COM or PInvoke 
interoperability, which can damage the stack.'
```

PS.

Im writing my program in C# using .NET 4.0 and x86 as Platform target to be able to run it also on older computers. I also tried using latest .NET 4.8 and x64/AnyCpu but nothing changed.

Comment: You mean `using (var client = new WebClient()) { // the rest }`. WebClient is not made for concurrent operations. Use a static HttpClient object instead.

Comment: @Jimi `HttpClient` is not available in .NET 4.0 unfortunatly.

Comment: Yes, it is: [Microsoft.Net.Http - NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) -- Note that you can also use HttpWebRequest, eventually; it works fine concurrently (if well configured / handled and if you remember that disposing disposable objects is not *optional*).

Comment: `/* more */` means what exactly?

Comment: @Charlieface basically parsing the string returned from the site and doing staff with it, nothing which matters / cause the exception.

Comment: Considering that .NET 4.0 was end-of-life in 2016, I suggest at the very least you upgrade to 4.8, to get security and bug fixes. Consider also transforming this into `async` and using `HttpClient`